# How do you make sure account has correct permissions ofr API on WHMCS?

Tags: php, whmcs

I am getting a error when I attempt to make a API call to the WHMCS External API. I am using a account that is an full administrator to generate the credentials and for the login link. Here is the links, some things changed for my own good. And the error that im getting.
https://orders.websitename.com/api.php?action=GetClientsProducts&identifier=identifier_key&secret=secret_key

https://orders.websitename.com/api.php?action=GetClientsProducts&username=user@company.com&password=password!&accesskey=secret_key

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<whmcsapi version="">
    <action>getclientsproducts</action>
    <result>error</result>
    <message>An admin user is required</message>
</whmcsapi>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should have been websitename.com/includes/api.php, the path for the api was wrong.